# How to create Dockerfile in Boot2docker to create an image

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

Can any one guide me how to create and edit a Dockerfile in boot2docker to create my own image? I am not sure which commands to use to edit the Dockerfile when in Boot2Docker shell.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you are looking to create your Dockerfile directly from the boot2docker shell. Once boot2docker is installed on your computer, you can directly create normally a Dockerfile from your shell. To do so, follow my steps :

1. Launch boot2docker and exports the env variables as requested (copy and paste the last three lines) [image: Boot2docker up]
2. Write the simplest test Dockerfile you can! [image: Dockerfile]
3. Build it (we will call our image 'test') [image: Build]
4. Let's run our image [image: Run]

Now you just have to adapt my example to do what you want. Keep in mind that in this example **the container we launched is now stopped** because nothing kept it alive. For most common cases, you will have something (like a server) which will keep your container running. I hope it will help you!

Comment: i am running boot2docker on a windows machine so when i directly launch the application i get connected to the boot2docker shell via ssh with docker@boot2docker as the root directory i am able to perform all the other docker operations like pull push run etc but i dont know how i would create my own Dockerfile and write the specific commands

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile is simply a text file with line-by-line instructions to build an image.  So you edit it with any text editor.

See the [Docker page](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) for further details on what to put inside.